# Query with database link server with pdo in php

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I'm facing a problem right now, i explain :

I have my SQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb, TO_CHAR(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') AS dateF, T1.IDCar, T2.IDMotor
FROM TDB2@MYLINKSERVER,T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE TDB2.IDCar = T1.IDCar
```

Which use a **TDB2@MYLINKSERVER** , to connect 2 differents databases from Oracle and use a table from and other database.

In fact, when i launch the query in sql developper, my query returns some datas.

So in php, i have

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('myquerybefore')
$sql->execute(array($annee));
$res = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And when i try to vardump my $res, it returns **array(0) { }** 
So i think that PDO don't use the @LINKSERVER to fetch results.

Any help would be appreciated
Sleakerz,

Comment: Works for me on Oracle 11.2/PHP 7. Verify your connection details and credentials.

Comment: @timclutton in fact : when i copy/paste this same query in sql developper , it works, and in PHP it didn't, i don't know why.

Comment: I don't know why either. Again, I can verify that database links work with PDO, at least in PHP 7 against Oracle 11.2. If _exactly_ the same query works in SQL Developer then chances are your PHP is connecting to a different database or with credentials that don't have the correct permissions. So, _Verify your connection details and credentials._

Comment: Do you give some constants or something ?
`public static function getPDOCDL()
    {
        $pdo = null;
        $db_username = "*****";
        $db_password = "*****";
        $db = " SID HERE";
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO($db,$db_username,$db_password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo ($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $pdo;
    }`
Do you speak about this for the credentials ?
It's the only place i have informations about my database, in fact i think PDO don't know the @DATABASE LINK SERVER

Comment: Database links are defined in Oracle; PDO doesn't need to know the linked server. It looks like your Oracle credentials and connection string are contained in `$db_username`, `$db_password`, and `$db`. Are these the same as you use in SQL Developer?

Comment: yes these are the same that i use in SQL Developper. 
I did a PhpInfo() , i have PHP 5.6.8, do you think it can be a reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make my query work : 
 I create a **synonym** with

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM LINKDATABASE 
   FOR TABLE1@THELINKDATABASE;
```

Then i have in my query: **FROM LINKDATABASE** which is my synonym !